# Android image handling- Any other better way to do this?

Tags: android, image, viewflipper

I have following code to show multiple large images using viewflipper

```
 viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
   // mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
    i.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    i.setImageResource(mImageIds[0]);

    ImageView i2 = new ImageView(this);
    i2.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    i2.setImageResource(mImageIds[1]);

    ImageView i3 = new ImageView(this);
    i3.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    i3.setImageResource(mImageIds[2]);
             .......
             .......


    viewFlipper.addView(i);
    viewFlipper.addView(i2);
    viewFlipper.addView(i3);
```

i have exactly 30 images, i'm going to create 30 child views for viewflipper.

My question is
1.What about performance if i create 30 views at a time (see above) 
2.can i reduce the Code
3.Any other right technique?

Answer (score 0):

I would actually prefer to use a gallery if I understand your idea correct.

Take a look at: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Please give us more information to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use for-each loop to reduce your code

```
void addImageView(){
        for (int imageId : mImageIds) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setImageResource(imageId);
        viewFlipper.addView(i);

        }

    }
```

Comment: @Saurabh yes... but i want to know can we use view flipper like this? creating 30 views at a time...